# AWS SDK - Writing a lambda to get all roles for the current account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

Working on writing a lambda to get all IAM roles within the current account using the AWS SDK documentation provided for Javascript: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html

However, my lambda keeps returning a null value, whereas I'm expecting it to return a list of existing roles in the response body:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var iam = new AWS.IAM();

    var roles = [];
    iam.listRoles(function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else roles.push(data);           // successful response
        const response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify(roles)
      };
      return response;
    });
 
};
```

I'm obviously missing something here. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an Old version of the AWS SDK for JavaScript. That doc you referenced is not the latest.

Try using the latest version as described in this ***AWS SDK for JavaScript DEV Guide V3*** here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/iam-examples-managing-users.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mixing up the async and callback, you can use promise to handle listRoles.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async event => {
  try {
    const iam = new AWS.IAM();
    const roles = await iam.listRoles().promise();

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(roles)
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
    return {
      statusCode: 200, // might change to error code here
      body: []
    };
  }
};
```